# Track what a user has seen/scrolled on a single page website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I read through all the other questions/answers I could find. Most solutions were quite old already and given that most websites nowadays are single page sites I am hoping there's an easier solution today?

I have a single page website i.e. home, banner, services, team, contact all on the same page with links at the top to scroll using href # to the section on the page.

Since all content is on one page, Google Analytcs only tracks the page as a whole. Is there an easy way to track whether a visitor has scrolled down to a specific section (website is a simple Bootstrap site) and/or clicked on a menu item to scroll down?

Comment: use something else like mouseflow or hotjar (which is the one i use in this cases, you can see also a video of what user have done)

Comment: Thanks @Berto99 I'll check that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a Virtual Pageview based on visibility element. Each section has a div, by assigning an ID to each section you can send a pageview as soon as the ID appears in the screen.

Depend on how your SPA works youca use History change trigger: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679322?hl=en&dark=0

Comment: Yes, that was something I was researching too.  Any chance you have a link to some sample html/javascript code?

Comment: Depend on how your website works (history change, etc...). Try ti check this documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Comment: @michelepisani OP uses GTM, above link is hardly helpful.

Comment: In this case writing on google "gtm tracking single page" you will find many resources. Obviously it is not a topic that can be described in a comment or in a post, but surely the approach is what I wrote to you in the message, also from GTM.