# How to track sections of a single page for google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a single page with 4 different sections like 1st section includes user info 2nd section shows user which slot is available , 3 section confirms the booking and 4th section does payment and completes the booking. So Before this I had different pages for each step but now everything is at one Page ,It is difficult for me to track them now ,Their URL's were different but now how am i gonna track through sections ?Please can anybody help .

Comment: Which one is it, Java or JavaScript? Since you also added jquery I assume you're refering to Javascript so the Java tag should be removed.

Comment: What exactly would you want to track? If the user sees the entire page, you'd have to track that. If you're making the sections visible as the user navigates the page you should be able to track the sections using JavaScript calls (not sure which ones).

Comment: Thank you for commenting ,I want to track sections ,like I want to know which section does drag users attention the most and users scrolled to which sections the most.

Comment: you can perfectly let google index a spa (single page application) u just have to add a routing eg. each section must be viewable by a specific url, google for "google index spa" and u will find lots

Comment: This might help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373401/track-what-a-user-has-seen-scrolled-on-a-single-page-website. However, your description seems to indicate your process requires a sequence of steps, e.g. "add/display user info", "show available slot", "make a booking", "confirm the booking", "make a payment". I assume those steps have to be taken anyway (maybe with a few exceptions) so wouldn't it make sense to track those instead of whether the according section was displayed or not?